# I would to know how to write select query with a break line between the concatenation of two columns values in the Gridview

Tags: sql, asp.net

I would to know how to write select query to add a break line between the concatenation of two columns values for showing in the Gridview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server:

```
select field1 + char(10) + field2 as something
```

In other database engines, it's the same general idea, different details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But I tested and it didn't show a new line . It just show a space between two column . Any advise please.

Comment: The line break is there.  Output it inside a textarea or a `<pre>` block to verify.  For display purposes, you have to replace the char(10) with a `<br>` tag.  You can do that either in your query or in your display code.  If you are observing the output in SSMS, copy and paste the result into notepad.  The line break will be there.